# Atom-Editor Remove snippit from language pack

Tags: python, atom-editor

How can I remove an annoying snippet from a language pack in Atom? In particular I find the `property` snippet from the `source.python` language pack super useful and it triggers everytime I want to add a property decorator.

Would love a way to remove it completely instead of just change the snippet replace content.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying that file will likely get overwritten when the language-html package gets updated. If you want to set a snippet for yourself, just modify your snippets.cson file. Find "Open your Snippets" in the Command Palette to open the file or open ~/.atom/snippets.cson.